# ASP.Net MVC Filter data using dropdownfield from Enum field EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums

I using ASP.Net 4.5 MVC EF6 Entity Framework

I have an Enum in my model.  I like to filter / sort the list by where clause on enum type field.To do this I build a DroppDownField. My SelectList:

```
 var  FGenre = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FileGenre)).Cast<FileGenre>().Select(c => new SelectListItem{ Text = c.ToString(), Value=  c.ToString() });
```

so I get a list (value and text are the text in the Enum).

Now I like to filter my data with 'Where' like:

```
var model =  db.Filetypes.Where(fg => fg.FileGenres.Equals(????????).);
```

1. How can I buid a where claus to filter by Enum

   or
2. How can I get a List for the DropDownList  with Value = Value(int) and Text, and how can I filter with the Enum( Int).

I'm still new to LINQ, Lambda and MVC in general. If someone has a way to better this code, please feel free to add in your views.

Edit:
My Model:

```
   public partial class Filetype
{

    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int FiletypeId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    [Display(Name="Datei Art")]
    public string TypeName { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Genre")]
    public FileGenre FileGenres { get; set; }

    .......

    public virtual ICollection<FiletypeRole> FiletypeRoles { get; set; }
}
public enum FileGenre
{
    NNB_A,
    NNB_B,
    NNB_C
}
```

Comment: Please can you post the definition of your Enum and FileTypes

Comment: var model =  db.Filetypes.Where(fg => fg.FileGenres == yourFileGenre).ToList(); doesn't work? "fg.FileGenres" is probably not a list so should not named in plural form

Comment: @Albero  I used this at first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the selectlist is representing the enum as a string, so you'd have to convert it to an enum in the query, which is rather ugly:

```
FileGenre MyGenre = (FileGenre) Enum.Parse(typeof(FileGenre), model.FileGenre, true);
```

So instead, you can use the enum with int values.  Declare it like this:

```
public enum FileGenre
{
    NNB_A = 1,
    NNB_B = 2,
    NNB_C = 3
}
```

And to populate the selectlist (Here I have created a method to return the selectlist):

```
public SelectList GetAsSelectList()
{
    var enumList = (from Enum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FileGenre))
                   select new 
                   {
                       Name = e,
                       Id = Convert.ToInt32(e).ToString()
                   }).ToList();
   return new SelectList((IEnumerable)enumList, "Id", "Name");
}
```

Now the selectlist will have an `int` value and will bind correctly when you POST it and use it in the filtering:

```
var model = db.Filetypes.Where(fg => fg.FileGenres == model.FileGenre).ToList();
```

As @Alberto mentioned, the `FileGenre` property on `Filetype` should be singular, as `FileGenres` make it seem like a collection or list, which could be confusing.

Comment: Yes you can put it in the controller. No that's not OK, you should fix the  error properly (you probably just need `using System.Collections;` at the top. How do you get the list? call the method ` var  FGenre = GetAsSelectList();`

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry I new im programming, First stepp is Ok. I use SelectList for my Dropdown and I get the List using your code.

Comment: When I use the filter i get Error that " ==  " not possible . So I try Equals for string and now  I get the message typ not comparable .

Comment: The Message is in german, i used the German version of VisualStudio 13. But I find a solusion. When I use the name of Enum I can filter with  these code      var model2 =  db.Filetypes.Where(fg => fg.FileGenres.ToString().Equals("Ort")).ToList();  That is Great

Comment: That's not a solution, it's just a workaround - it bypasses the enum binding completely and leaves you where you started - ie filtering on strings! Oh well, as long as you're happy...